Assigning value from previous row works only once. Don't fill whole column
I have data wchich have value only in the first row of series. Like this:
data <- data_frame(no = c(1:10), day = c("day 1", NA, NA, NA, "day2", NA, NA, "day3", NA, NA))

      no day  
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 day 1
 2     2 NA   
 3     3 NA   
 4     4 NA   
 5     5 day2 
 6     6 NA   
 7     7 NA   
 8     8 day3 
 9     9 NA   
10    10 NA   

I want to fill down values until day is changed. Like below.
      no day  
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 day 1
 2     2 day 1   
 3     3 day 1   
 4     4 day 1   
 5     5 day2 
 6     6 day2   
 7     7 day2   
 8     8 day3 
 9     9 day3   
10    10 day3   

I was thinking that it is kind of easy.
data <- data %>%  
  mutate(day = if_else(is.na(day),
                       lag(day),
                       day))

To my suprise it works in strange way:
      no day  
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 day 1
 2     2 day 1
 3     3 NA   
 4     4 NA   
 5     5 day2 
 6     6 day2 
 7     7 NA   
 8     8 day3 
 9     9 day3 
10    10 NA  

It replaces only the first NA in series.
I have no idea why. I hoped that in the time of evaluation of the thrid row the second should already have value from the first. Am I wrong?
I've tried is.null and is_null instead is.na but it gives error.
I've also tried day = day %||% lag(day) but it doesn't work (no error, just no effect - %||% is working because day = lag(day) %||% day fills all column with NA)
Can somebody expalain me why it doesn't work?
I already found topic 14900165 and zoo::na.locf() works.
Still want to understand wchy my first code doesn't work...
thx
Radek
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Warsaw
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggrepel_0.9.5    hrbrthemes_0.8.7 gt_0.11.0        janitor_2.2.0   
 [5] webchem_1.3.0    lubridate_1.9.3  forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.1   
 [9] dplyr_1.1.4      purrr_1.0.2      readr_2.1.5      tidyr_1.3.1     
[13] tibble_3.2.1     ggplot2_3.5.1    tidyverse_2.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.5            xfun_0.47               tzdb_0.4.0             
 [4] vctrs_0.6.5             tools_4.4.1             generics_0.1.3         
 [7] parallel_4.4.1          fansi_1.0.6             pkgconfig_2.0.3        
[10] lifecycle_1.0.4         compiler_4.4.1          munsell_0.5.1          
[13] data.tree_1.1.0         snakecase_0.11.1        fontquiver_0.2.1       
[16] fontLiberation_0.1.0    htmltools_0.5.8.1       yaml_2.3.10            
[19] Rttf2pt1_1.3.12         pillar_1.9.0            crayon_1.5.3           
[22] extrafontdb_1.0         fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1 tidyselect_1.2.1       
[25] rvest_1.0.4             digest_0.6.37           stringi_1.8.4          
[28] showtextdb_3.0          extrafont_0.19          fastmap_1.2.0          
[31] grid_4.4.1              colorspace_2.1-1        cli_3.6.3              
[34] magrittr_2.0.3          utf8_1.2.4              withr_3.0.1            
[37] gdtools_0.4.0           scales_1.3.0            showtext_0.9-7         
[40] bit64_4.0.5             timechange_0.3.0        httr_1.4.7             
[43] sysfonts_0.8.9          bit_4.0.5               hms_1.1.3              
[46] knitr_1.48              rlang_1.1.4             Rcpp_1.0.13            
[49] glue_1.7.0              xml2_1.3.6              renv_1.0.7             
[52] rstudioapi_0.16.0       vroom_1.6.5             jsonlite_1.8.8         
[55] R6_2.5.1                systemfonts_1.1.0      
> 


You might want to run data$day = gsub(" ", "", data$day) first.

/../I hoped that in the time of evaluation of the thrid row the second should already have value from the first./../ . There's no iteration or element-wise update and re-evaluation; if_else() is vectorized, it first evaluates both true & false expressions (lagged day and day as-is) and then, in one go, subsets values form one or another according to condition argument.

In order to solve easily your issue there is already in the metapackage tidyverse and tidyr package a function named tidyr::fill
usage:
tidy_pets <- tibble::tribble(
  ~rank, ~pet_type, ~breed,
  1L,        NA,    "Boston Terrier",
  2L,        NA,    "Retrievers (Labrador)",
  3L,        NA,    "Retrievers (Golden)",
  4L,        NA,    "French Bulldogs",
  5L,        NA,    "Bulldogs",
  6L,     "Dog",    "Beagles",
  1L,        NA,    "Persian",
  2L,        NA,    "Maine Coon",
  3L,        NA,    "Ragdoll",
  4L,        NA,    "Exotic",
  5L,        NA,    "Siamese",
  6L,     "Cat",    "American Short"
)
tidy_pets %>%
  fill(pet_type, .direction = "up")
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>     rank pet_type breed                
#>    <int> <chr>    <chr>                
#>  1     1 Dog      Boston Terrier       
#>  2     2 Dog      Retrievers (Labrador)
#>  3     3 Dog      Retrievers (Golden)  
#>  4     4 Dog      French Bulldogs      
#>  5     5 Dog      Bulldogs             
#>  6     6 Dog      Beagles              
#>  7     1 Cat      Persian              
#>  8     2 Cat      Maine Coon           
#>  9     3 Cat      Ragdoll              
#> 10     4 Cat      Exotic               
#> 11     5 Cat      Siamese              
#> 12     6 Cat      American Short       


So in your case you need to perform:
tidyr::fill(data, day, .direction = "down")


You have confused ?stats::lag and ?dplyr::lag which don't do the same thing really. As per your link stats::lag "will not work with a vector, data frame, or another variable, other than a time series." I'd remove that link at the top of your post as it will be confusing for anyone already working with dplyr

Agreed, this is highly confusing if not wrong. Also, why a whole {tidyverse} if tidyr::fill(df, day, .direction = "down") is all and given in the linked dupe?

What is happening in your code is explained below by generating two more columns: one based on lag function (lag_day) and another column day2 corresponding to what you obtained.
You are saying that if day column is missing, then the value from column lag_day should be used; otherwise the value from column day should be used. And the result of this operation is shown in column day2.
   no   day lag_day  day2
1   1 day 1    <NA> day 1
2   2  <NA>   day 1 day 1
3   3  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
4   4  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
5   5  day2    <NA>  day2
6   6  <NA>    day2  day2
7   7  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
8   8  day3    <NA>  day3
9   9  <NA>    day3  day3
10 10  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>

# code used
data |> 
  mutate(lag_day = lag(day), day2=if_else(is.na(day), lag(day), day))

You could solve your problem as follow:
data$day = zoo::na.locf(data$day)

or
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  mutate(day = zoo::na.locf(day))


If the real data has the same simple structure as the toy data, we can use rle() and rep() from base:
rep(data0$day[i<-!is.na(data0$day)], 
    with(rle(i), lengths[values==FALSE])+1L)

giving
[1] "day 1" "day 1" "day 1" "day 1" "day2"  "day2"  "day2"  "day3"  "day3"  "day3" 

where data0 is the toy data. Assigned to data0$day gives
> transform(data0, day = rep(day[i<-!is.na(day)], 
                             with(rle(i), lengths[values==FALSE])+1L))
   no   day
1   1 day 1
2   2 day 1
3   3 day 1
4   4 day 1
5   5  day2
6   6  day2
7   7  day2
8   8  day3
9   9  day3
10 10  day3

Edit. Cleaning data first.
> transform(data0, day = rep(sub(" ", "", day)[i<-!is.na(day)], 
                             with(rle(i), lengths[values==FALSE])+1L))
   no  day
1   1 day1
2   2 day1
3   3 day1
4   4 day1
5   5 day2
6   6 day2
7   7 day2
8   8 day3
9   9 day3
10 10 day3

